# applying window function to big data set (how to optimize?)

Tags: hive, bigdata, presto

I have to do some data analysis on a table with 400+ million rows. I got this to work on a small sample but I'm sure it will run out of memory in production.

The table structure is like this (for millions of serial numbers):

```
+------------+---------------+------------+----------+
|    date    | serial_number |  status_1  | status_2 |
+------------+---------------+------------+----------+
| 10/1/2018  |           123 | warehouse  | v        |
| 10/10/2018 |           123 | warehouse  | w        |
| 10/20/2018 |           123 | warehouse  | x        |
| 11/2/2018  |           123 | in transit | y        |
+------------+---------------+------------+----------+
```

I need to get the dates where status_1 = 'in transit' currently and status_2 = 'x' on a previous date. That should look like this:

```
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------+------------+
|  date_1   | serial_number |  status_1  | status_2 |   date_2   |
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------+------------+
| 11/2/2018 |           123 | in transit | x        | 10/20/2018 |
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------+------------+
```

I got it using two rank functions, but this will probably choke on a big table.

```
with transit as (
select 
*
from (
    select *,
    rank() over(partition by serial_number order by date desc) rnk
    from sample_t 
    order by serial_number, date asc
    ) 
where rnk=1 and status_1 = 'in transit'
),
x_type as (
select 
*
from (
    select *,
    rank() over(partition by serial_number order by date desc) rnk
    from sample_t 
    order by serial_number, date asc
    ) 
where rnk>1 and status_2 = 'x'
)
select tr.date date_1,
tr.serial_number,
tr.status_1,
x.status_2,
x.date date_2
from transit tr left join x_type x on tr.serial_number = x.serial_number
```

I can't see how to do this with one rank function. Is there a better, more efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lag` to do this.

```
select *
from (select t.*
      ,lag(status_2) over(partition by serial_no order by date) as prev_status_2
      ,lag(date) over(partition by serial_no order by date) as prev_date
      from tbl t  
     ) t 
where status_1 = 'in_transit' and prev_status_2 = 'x'
```